# CreateDebugMainDexClassList Error in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i got this error when i am adding few libraries in android studio ?.

Suggestions to solve this bug would be appreciated.

Comment: run `gradlew assembleDebug --info` and get more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you experience this problem after adding a few libraries to your project.

It is very possible that you have run into a situation where your project now exceeds the 65K method count limit.

There are a few ways to handle this:

1. Multidex - https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
2. Stripping old unused libraries to reduce your method count

Multidex has its ups and downs so I advice trying option 2 first to figure out your current method count.

This gradle plugin allows you to do that: https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

You can also dig deeper and see how many methods a package has.

Comment: I am using Appium library for my project. I enabled that multidex to True in my gradle, even-though i am facing that issue. Earlier i faced some multidex error...Duplicate classes in some activities like that..Then i excluded that duplicate libraries too...